ASP.NET Boilerplate: Long Load Time for ABP Dynamic Scripts
I'm using the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework in my application, and I'm experiencing significant load times for the following script:
<!-- Dynamic scripts of ABP system (They are created on runtime and can not be bundled) -->
<script src="~/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?v=@(AppTimes.StartupTime.Ticks)" type="text/javascript"></script>

This script takes too long to load, impacting the performance of my application. I've tried several optimizations but haven't found a solution that works. Here are some specifics about my setup:

Framework: ASP.NET core Boilerplate
Issue: Long load time for dynamically generated scripts
Script: ~/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?v=@(AppTimes.StartupTime.Ticks)

Steps I've Taken:

Verified that the script is not cached and is loaded fresh each time.
Ensured that the server and database performance are optimized.
Checked network latency and bandwidth.

Questions:

What could be causing this long load time for the dynamically generated ABP scripts?
Are there any known issues or configurations in ASP.NET Boilerplate that might affect the load
time of these scripts?
How can I optimize or troubleshoot the loading of these dynamic scripts?

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Open issue from abp side
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/16075
